# Styling with Pseudo Class After and Before closing element

Tags: css

I have written a specific code, for the entire functionality of the website, but now the client want a specific area to look a little different what I can do is make a separate code for it, but I believe there is a way to do it in CSS if perhaps some one can guide me to the right direction ?

my css code is

```
<ul class="item-address">
<li><span>Jan</span> 
logist 
<span>Timing: </span>
all days 4 pm to 6 pm except sunday 
<span>Fees: </span>
1000</li>
<li>
<span>oka</span>
Coder 
<span>Timing: </span>
mon 2 pm 4 pm 
<span>Fees: </span>
1000</li>
    </ul>
```

Now the only thing I want is to make a div after the closing  how to use after and before pseudo class in this case where the div will be created for after span in my case for logist ?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you intend but you can you try something like this:

```css
.item-address li:first-child span:first-child::after {
    content: " (new content here) ";
    background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<ul class="item-address">
    <li>
        <span>Jan</span>
        logist
        <span>Timing: </span>
        all days 4 pm to 6 pm except sunday
        <span>Fees: </span>
        1000
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>oka</span>
        Coder
        <span>Timing: </span>
        mon 2 pm 4 pm
        <span>Fees: </span>
        1000
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hq47jepq/1/)

Comment: but I want content to appear after closing span

Comment: What closing span? You have several span there

Comment: all of the span like for example <span>jan</span> <div class=this is wat i want> Logist </div this is what before span i want>

Comment: @UbaidRehman, it is an easy thing to fix, I just don't know exactly what you need. Let me ask you some things to see if I understand: you want the word `logist` to be styled? Can the HTML structure be altered? Can you add a div that contains `logist`?

Comment: I assume you are answering to my first question. The word logist can be styled without altering the HTML structure but it will affect other words in the same condition. So, if you can't alter the HTML, it isn't possible to style that word as it's not wrapped in any specific element. It is wrapped in `li` but so are the other words. [Here's the maximum I got](https://jsfiddle.net/hq47jepq/2/). You must alter the HTML in order to style only that word (for example, wrap it in a span, div or whatever)

Comment: great idea, dear but can we use ::after here to put a div after span ?

Comment: No, to add a `div` element to the HTML you must use javascript. Since you want to use CSS only, the best you can do is use an approach as I showed above or similar